# Unexpected behavior from changing owner in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have a schema of tables `myschema` with different owners in postgres - owner 'foo' and owner 'bar'

After granting all privileges on the database to owner 'bar', and then re-logging in as user 'bar', I try to change the ownership of all bar-owned tables to 'foo' with the following command:

```
SELECT format(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I OWNER TO %I;',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  'foo'  
)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
```

This then returns:

```
 ALTER TABLE my_db.my_schema.my_tableA OWNER TO foo;
 ALTER TABLE my_db.my_schema.my_tableB OWNER TO foo;
 ALTER TABLE my_db.my_schema.my_tableC OWNER TO foo;
```

successfully

Then, when I run `select * from pg_tables;`, I see that none of the tableowners have changed.  How is this possible and what could be happening?

Comment: Did you `commit;` the changes?

Comment: Should COMMIT come at the end of the statement?

Comment: After all statements.

Comment: I just get WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
COMMIT

Comment: OK, then it must be something different.

Comment: One would expect an error if you did not have the proper authority.  But as you do not mention an error it raises the question: Did you subsequently run the statements? The "Select ..." builds the statement but **it does not execute** them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change ownership of tables from `bar` to `foo`, a user must be a member of both roles. So if `bar` should be able to do that, it must be a superuser or a member of `foo`:

```
GRANT foo TO bar;
```

I guess your statements caused an error that you somehow failed to see and didn't do anything.